# C undeclared variable for pyramid

Tags: c, variables, cs50

I'm writing this since I have tried for a while but haven't gotten any success. I will post my code and the error message (which is from the cs50 week1 course).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    do { 
        int h = get_int("Height of your pyramid please\n");   
    } 
    while(h < 1 && h > 8); 
} 
    
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) { 
            printf (" "); 
        } 
            
        for(int k = h; k < h; k--) { 
            printf(" # "); 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
            
    }
```

And the error message is as follows : "mario.c:12:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'h'

By "undeclared identifier," clang means you've used a name h on line 12 of mario.c which hasn't been defined. If you mean to use h as a variable, make sure to declare it by specifying its type, and check that the variable name is spelled correctly.". Also the code is supposed to make a pyramid that faces right.
Thanks for your help!
Ragnaroni
PS : if anything is weird looking sorry and tell me how to correct it and I will.

Comment: You declare the variable `h` inside of the `do-while` loop, which means you can't use it outside of the loop. Just declare it like `int h;` before the loop.

Comment: also as a SO tip use code-fences to formate text as code just put a line of `~~~` before and after the code.

Comment: your for loop is outside of the main() function. And it'll be a good idea to declare h outside of the do-while function. Proper formatting is a weapon in coding

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you following correction concerning the `h` problem:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    int h; // this is the height of the pyramid
    do { 
        h = get_int("Height of your pyramid please\n");   
    } 
    while(h < 1 && h > 8); 
    
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) { 
            printf (" "); 
        } 
            
        for(int k = h; k < h; k--) { 
            printf(" # "); 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
            
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've made sure that everything is inside the `main` loop, and I've put the declaration of your variable on such a location that it's accessible by all places which use it.

Comment: Thanks but can I ask a follow up question? So i corrected my code however the right facing pyramid doesn't display and instead displays this:
"clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    mario.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o mario"
and I don't know what this is supposed to mean...
It doesn't prompt me for the height.

Comment: Edit : the question is prompted, however the pyramid doesn't show but I'll try to figure it out like I did with the the prompt.

Comment: OK so I've worked on it further, I noticed my "while" function doesn't do its job properly, it's supposed to keep prompting you if h is over 8 or under 1. And the other issue is that the pyramid doesn't look proper, I get a square. Here's the code: 
(in the next message since it doesn't fit lol)

Comment: #include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void){ 
 
    int h; //pyramid height
    do { 
        h = get_int("Height of your pyramid please\n"); 
    } while(h < 1 && h > 8); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
        
            for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
            
             printf("."); 
                
            } 
           
                for(int k = h; k < h; k++){ 
            
                    printf("#"); 
                    
                    } 
                    
            printf("\n"); 
            
        }
}

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three basic issues:

1. The `for` loop is outside of the `main()` function. This is not permissible in C. Any control flow statements need to be inside of a function and not at global scope.
2. `h` is declared/defined new at each iteration inside of the `do while` loop in `main()`. If you want `h` to be visible outside of the loop, you need to declare it outside of the loop.
3. Your `do while` loop condition of `h < 1 && h > 8` doesn't make sense. It checks whether `h` is below `1` **and** at the same time above `8`. This will never be the case so the result is just going one time through the loop's body which makes the loop pretty useless.